# Finding which region's app store iOS app is downloaded from

Tags: ios, itunes-store, itunes-sdk

I need to show legal information based on which app store user used to download the app.
I understand i can't access user's iTunes account information from my app.

Are there any alternate ways to get to know about the store info.

Comment: Perhaps a better title would be "Finding which **region's** app store iOS app is downloaded from". Right now, the title alone suggests one of many possible, different stores (e.g. Cydia). Not sure enough to edit, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i could find is upload different builds in different region app store.Those builds should be having an entry of "Localization native development region" which should set to english/german/spanish etc in the info.plist and read that value in your code to find out which language is set for  key "kCFBundleDevelopmentRegionKey" and show the legal information according to that.